# Gave daughter my macbook pro and 6plus for college & she is getting msgs etc under my name. What to do?

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, icloud, photos

I gave my daughter my macbook pro and my older 6plus for college/ seemingly still knows me because she is getting msg photo library etc for me. Was it not wiped totally? Help please. I do still see two iphones when my devices are listed.

Comment: Your daughter's MacBook Pro is likely logged into your iCloud account. She can check under System Preferences/iCloud.

Comment: Have you done a fresh system install on both before handing them over?

Comment: Straight from Apple, this is what you should have done, and should do! Have a look at: [What to do before you sell or give away your Mac](https://support.apple.com/HT201065) **&** [What to do before you sell or give away your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch](https://support.apple.com/HT201351)

Answer (score 1):

At a minimum you will need to make sure both devices are completely signed out of iCloud.  This will require your daughter knowing your iCloud password if she is not close by enough for you to do it.  I would recommend changing it immediately after if you do tell her.

Personally I would also do an Erase All Contents and Settings on the iPhone and a clean install on the MacBook Pro as well.